# How to pivot two rows into one based on date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CreatedDate                  TargetDate               Value        Name     rowNum
2016-10-06 16:30:00.000 2016-10-16 00:00:00.000     17.97566      Joseph      1
2016-10-06 16:20:00.000 2016-10-16 00:00:00.000     1.176129      Heidi       1
2016-10-06 16:20:00.000 2016-10-15 23:00:00.000     1.196976      Heidi       1
2016-10-06 16:30:00.000 2016-10-15 23:00:00.000     15.15687      Joseph      1
2016-10-06 16:30:00.000 2016-10-15 22:00:00.000     11.04526      Joseph      1
2016-10-06 16:20:00.000 2016-10-15 22:00:00.000     1.539218      Heidi       1
```

And I would like to pivot it into a table like this:

```
gen_dt_Joseph           gen_dt_Heidi            TargetDate              JosephValue     HeidiValue
2016-10-06 16:30:00.000 2016-10-06 16:20:00.000 2016-10-16 00:00:00.000 17.9757         1.1761
2016-10-06 16:30:00.000 2016-10-06 16:20:00.000 2016-10-15 23:00:00.000 15.1569         1.1970
2016-10-06 16:30:00.000 2016-10-06 16:20:00.000 2016-10-15 22:00:00.000 11.0453         1.5392
```

My query looks like this:

```
select CreatedDate as gen_dt_Joseph 
  ,CreatedDate as gen_dt_Heidi
  ,TargetDate  [TargetDate]
  ,[Joseph]   [JosephValue]
  ,[Heidi] [HeidiValue]
 FROM theTable
 pivot (max(value) for Name in ( [Joseph],[Heidi])
 ) as pvt
order by TargetDate DESC
```

Of course this is returning:

```
gen_dt_Joseph           gen_dt_Heidi            TargetDate              JosephValue     HeidiValue
2016-10-06 16:30:00.000 2016-10-06 16:30:00.000 2016-10-16 00:00:00.000 17.9757         NULL
2016-10-06 16:20:00.000 2016-10-06 16:20:00.000 2016-10-16 00:00:00.000 NULL         1.1761
2016-10-06 16:30:00.000 2016-10-06 16:30:00.000 2016-10-15 23:00:00.000 15.1569         NULL
2016-10-06 16:20:00.000 2016-10-06 16:20:00.000 2016-10-15 23:00:00.000 NULL         1.1970
2016-10-06 16:30:00.000 2016-10-06 16:30:00.000 2016-10-15 22:00:00.000 11.0453         NULL
2016-10-06 16:20:00.000 2016-10-06 16:20:00.000 2016-10-15 22:00:00.000 NULL         1.5392
```

So basically I want one record containing two values for each TargetDate, but if I have two different CreatedDate's I want to record the most recent one for each record.  Can anyone help me take the final step here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When having to pivot multiple columns I prefer to simply use the `CASE WHEN` statement combined with a standard `GROUP BY` clause. The following query will give you the desired result .

```
SELECT      MAX(
                CASE Name 
                    WHEN    'Joseph' THEN CreatedDate
                    ELSE    NULL
                END
            ) AS gen_dt_Joseph
            ,MAX(
                CASE Name 
                    WHEN    'Heidi' THEN CreatedDate
                    ELSE    NULL
                END
            ) AS gen_dt_Heidi
            ,TargetDate
            ,MAX(
                CASE Name 
                    WHEN    'Joseph' THEN Value
                    ELSE    NULL
                END
            ) AS JosephValue
            ,MAX(
                CASE Name 
                    WHEN    'Heidi' THEN Value
                    ELSE    NULL
                END
            ) AS HeidiValue
FROM        theTable
GROUP BY    TargetDate
ORDER BY    TargetDate DESC
```